# Better way to instantiate child classes with shared interface/baseclass

Tags: java

I'm new to Java so this is likely pretty easy. I have a series of subclasses that share most variables/methods with an interface, but each child class has a few additional methods unique to their type which is why I designed the code this way.

However, when I retrieve data from a database (the data is stored in the same format for every subclass I have) I'd like to be able to create an instance of a base class or something that I can easily either cast to the subclass I need or have some sort of factory to give me a child class instance.

This is the code I have now, it just checks what type the data is for and then creates a new instance of the subclass but it feels so repetitive to me.

Anything better?

```
                if( rs.getString("action_type").equals("block-break") || rs.getString("action_type").equals("block-place") ){
                actions.add( new BlockAction(
                        rs.getString("action_time"),
                        rs.getString("action_type"),
                        rs.getString("world"),
                        rs.getString("player"),
                        rs.getInt("x"),
                        rs.getInt("y"),
                        rs.getInt("z"),
                        rs.getString("data")
                    ) );
            }

            if( rs.getString("action_type").equals("entity-kill") ){
                actions.add( new EntityKillAction(
                        rs.getString("action_time"),
                        rs.getString("action_type"),
                        rs.getString("world"),
                        rs.getString("player"),
                        rs.getInt("x"),
                        rs.getInt("y"),
                        rs.getInt("z"),
                        rs.getString("data")
                    ) );
            }
```

Comment: Do the objects you are creating have more than one constructor?  Do they have a default (empty) constructor as well as the one that takes 8 parameters as you have shown?

Comment: They do have two different constructors in each child class. There's no empty default one.

Comment: Are the multiple constructors the same in each class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what is `actions` in your question but here is a way you can avoid repetitive and get simpler code.

```
BaseAction baseAction ; // super class
String actionType = rs.getString("action_type"); 
if (actionType.equals("block-break") || actionType.equals("block-place")) {
   BlockAction blockAction = new BlockAction(); // create instance for sub class
   blockAction.set() // set sub class attributes here
   baseAction = blockAction ;

} else if (actionType.equals("entity-kill")) {
   EntityKillAction entityKillAction =new EntityKillAction(); //another subClass
   entityKillAction.set() 
   baseAction = entityKillAction;
}
//set all super class atributes for all
baseAction.setActionTime(rs.getString("action_time"));
baseAction.setActionType(rs.getString("action_type")) ;
// similarly set for all attributes  
actions.add(baseAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better if you can use the factory pattern approach to create instance of classes.

Please have look this link

[Java Patterns](http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/java_design_patterns.htm)